# Cluster IP can belong to other network?

Tags: networking, load-balancing, network-protocols, network-interface

I have 3 internet networks from 3 routers. I have 1 static IP from each network. Can I make one static IP as Virtual IP (cluster IP for load balancing) and other 2 static IPs as physical IP address (2 node servers) ? If yes, any ports should be enabled? Any help?

Comment: Which implementation of load-balancing are you going to use? In what environment?

Comment: I will be using load balancer feature given by Windows Server 2016 OS

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9EX0lS-J0oE   going to implement NLB as given in this link

Comment: @Belegnar  iam using Network load balancing given by Windows OS. Can you comment with your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched and found that different SubNet IPs load balancing not possible with Windows OS NLB feature, but possible with any other LoadBalancer which is not related to Windows OS NLB.